# Symfony2 Separate crud form from controller

Tags: php, symfony

I used the `./app/console generate:doctrine:crud` command and noticed how it created new methods in my controller: "createCreateForm", "createEditForm" and "createDeleteForm". Is there a way to create these crud forms within the single FormType instead?

When we look at the generated `createEditForm` method, it looks like this:

```
private function createEditForm(MyEntity $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('MyEntity_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
```

The `buildForm` method in `FormType`.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
    ;
}
```

Is there a better practise, like passing settings directly to the buildForm method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `FormTypeInterface#setDefaultOptions`:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));
}
```

You shouldn't do this with the action option, as that's something that should be defined by your controller. Your form type shouldn't know about the URL architecture of your application.

Comment: Thank you. I take it that the FormType should be reusable in every scenario where the entity is used.

Answer (score 1):

These should remain here, remember that symfony2 uses the mvc pattern, so the entities of your aplication should not contain code related to either views or controllers.